# Showing related questions from MathOverflow

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, related-questions

I'm a professional mathematician but I usually have non-professional questions, or perhaps some dumb professional ones that do not reach “research level”. Nevertheless, I think that sometimes it might be useful that when asking a question, related content from MO be suggested to me: Either in the form of *Questions that may already have your answer* or *Similar Questions*.

Would this feature be of use for someone else?

Comment: It would certainly be useful (+1). Sadly, it's unlikely to be implemented. Nothing else on the site uses such cross-database queries as far as I know, so there'd be some infrastructure to put in place for this to happen.

Comment: I think you're right, Normal Human. But gosh, this would be nice.